# Record is empty?

Tags: class, delphi, data-structures, types, record

Is there any data in a Record Type with Delphi? How is it understood?

For example, supposedly get a Record Type like this;

```
type
  TDummy = PACKED record
    Text   : String;
    Number : Integer;
  end;
var
  aRecord : TDummy;
begin
  aRecord := default(TDummy);   // In this state "aRecord" is empty. (Text = '' and Number = 0)
  aRecord.Text := 'TEST';       // This is no longer empty
end;
```

So is there any way to figure out this without browsing through the Record Items?

Comment: "In this state "aRecord" is empty" No, it is not empty. It contains the empty string and the number 0.

Comment: Yes you are right. I ask, how do I know if he's exactly like this?

Comment: The best approach is to declare a method `TDummy.IsEmpty: Boolean`.

Comment: Can you give a simple example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Using a member function

By far the cleanest approach, IMHO, is to declare a method `TDummy.IsEmpty: Boolean`:

```pascal
type
  TDummy = record
    Text: string;
    Number: Integer;
    function IsEmpty: Boolean;
  end;

{ TDummy }

function TDummy.IsEmpty: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Text = '') and (Number = 0);
end;
```

Then you can always use this method to see if the record is empty:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  D: TDummy;
begin

  D := Default(TDummy);

  if D.IsEmpty then
    ShowMessage('D is empty.');

  D.Number := 394;

  if D.IsEmpty then
    ShowMessage('D is empty.');

end;
```

## Using the equals operator

A different approach:

```pascal
type
  TDummy = record
    Text: string;
    Number: Integer;
    class operator Equal(const Left, Right: TDummy): Boolean;
    class operator NotEqual(const Left, Right: TDummy): Boolean;
  end;

const
  EmptyDummy: TDummy = ();

{ TDummy }

class operator TDummy.Equal(const Left, Right: TDummy): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Left.Text = Right.Text) and (Left.Number = Right.Number);
end;

class operator TDummy.NotEqual(const Left, Right: TDummy): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not (Left = Right);
end;
```

Now you can do

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  D: TDummy;
begin

  D := Default(TDummy);

  if D = EmptyDummy then
    ShowMessage('D is empty.');

  D.Number := 394;

  if D = EmptyDummy then
    ShowMessage('D is empty.');

end;
```

## Crazy stuff

If you absolutely do not want to compare each member separately, you can under some circumstances compare the bytes.

But please notice that in general, you cannot compare two records by comparing their bytes. Just to mention two obvious reasons:

1. String members may be semantically equal even though they are represented by two different string heap objects (so that comparer says "not equal" while in fact they are equal).
2. Records may have padding if they are not `packed` (so the comparer might say "not equal" while in fact they are equal).

But you only want to compare against the "default" (zeroed) value, and as a bonus your record type happens to be `packed`, so you could get away with

```pascal
type
  TDummy = packed record
    Text: string;
    Number: Integer;
  end;

  TZeroRecord<T: record> = record
    class function IsZero([Ref] const ARecord: T): Boolean; static;
  end;

{ TZeroRecord<T> }

class function TZeroRecord<T>.IsZero([Ref] const ARecord: T): Boolean;
begin
  var DefT := Default(T);
  Result := CompareMem(@ARecord, @DefT, SizeOf(T));
end;
```

and

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  D: TDummy;
begin

  D := Default(TDummy);

  if TZeroRecord<TDummy>.IsZero(D) then
    ShowMessage('D is empty.');

  D.Number := 394;

  if TZeroRecord<TDummy>.IsZero(D) then
    ShowMessage('D is empty.');

end;
```

But this is fairly crazy.

Comment: @CivatA: Yes, but that would IMHO be very overkill and it would be orders of magnitude slower (which in most cases isn't a big deal since computers these days are really fast, though).

Comment: Since you only compare against *zero*, I don't think so. All empty strings should be the `nil` pointer, all empty dynamic arrays, object references, and interfaces as well. And you only read. The worst thing that could happen is a false "it's non-zero", for instance if you in the future would add a record *member* and *it* would not be `packed`.

Comment: I have learned a lot from you right now. Thanks dude.
I think a statement like this might be even simpler;

`
function TDummy.IsEmpty: Boolean;
var
  DefT: TDummy;
begin
  DefT := Default(TDummy);
  Result := CompareMem(@Self, @DefT, SizeOf(TDummy));
end;
`

Comment: @CivatA: True. But the point of my `TZeroRecord` is that you can define that type *once* and then use it for all your (present and future) packed record types (not only your `TDummy` today, but also your `TFrog` and `TProcyonidae` of tomorrow). (So you don't need to define the `IsEmpty` method every time you create a new packed record type.)